# How do I work out spec of 24v dc motor?

Tags: dc-motor, stepper-motor

I have a motor in a vending machine (picture) it only has these numbers on.
[image]

What I'm hoping to do is turn the motor on and off.  However I have no idea what this motor is aside from 24v dc.

How do I work out what the RPM / wattage / Spec of the motor is?

Answer (score 1):

You can take some of the numbers from the motor's label and do a internet search for them. You might get lucky and match a manufacturer's part number.

Other than that, take measurements. Measure the current, calculate power. Measuring RPM can be done with a stopwatch, a video camera, or more sophisticated methods depending on the approximate range of RPM values.

Comment: Since this is looks like a brushed DC motor, perhaps the RPM can also be deduced from the current consumption fluctuations observed on an oscilloscope. I've never tried that so I cannot vouch that it would work. Something to try out on a rainy sunday perhaps.

Comment: You may be able to confirm that it is a brushed motor by looking for tiny sparks in the vent holes. Little brushed motors like this run really fast unloaded, thousands of RPM.

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that you will find published data for a motor removed from a product. Such motors are often designed and manufactured for one specific product.

You can determine quite a bit by performing tests. You need to be able to measure DC current and DC voltage. It would be very helpful to have an adjustable-voltage DC power supply.

Measure the current and voltage at rated voltage and no-load, motor running with nothing attached to the shaft. Calculate the power. The calculated power gives you the no-load losses. Even if you have a fixed-voltage DC power supply, measure the voltage for each test condition.

Measure the no-load speed. You will need a tachometer to do that. There are inexpensive tachometers that measure the speed based on reflections from reflective tape attached to the shaft. If the motor is attached to a speed reduction gear, you may be able to count output shaft revolutions, but the gear is a significant load on the motor and that will mean that you can only characterize the gear-motor combination. The motor's speed constant is the speed divided by the voltage.

Measure the stall current. To do that, you need to be able to hold the shaft so that it is prevented from turning. With a small motor, that may cause damage within a very few seconds. It is probably best to do that with greatly reduced voltage. You can calculate the resistance of the motor based on stall current and voltage and use that to calculate the stall current at rated voltage.

Measure the stall torque. You can do that by attaching a rod perpendicular to the shaft. Measure the force required prevent the shaft from turning using a postal scale or something like that.

The motor's torque constant is the stall torque divided by the stall current.

Measure the length and diameter of the motor housing. That will allow you to find specifications for motors that have a similar no-load speed, stall torque and no-load losses. That will allow you to estimate what continuous load torque the motor can handle without overheating.

Look at the answer given by @Phil G to [how-to-measure-dc-motor-used-as-generator-efficiency-using-homebrew-methods](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/435462/how-to-measure-dc-motor-used-as-generator-efficiency-using-homebrew-methods)