# How to derive the driving voltage and specifications of a DC motor?

Tags: dc-motor

I have lots of small DC motors that I want to classify and measure its specs. 
Unfortunately with the years I have lost all datasheets for them, so I need to measure them manually.

[This](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/346998/voltage-current-torque-and-speed-in-dc-motors) post described well the proprieties of a DC motor. So:

- T ∝ I (torque is proportional to the current)
- V = I•R + Emf
- Emf ∝ w (Emf voltage is proportional to the rotation speed)

Resulting in the following graph:

[image: img]

Tools I have at disposition:

- multimeter
- An electric screwdriver with known RPM
- Different voltage DC sources

I will probably be able to measure:

- resistance
- no load and stall current
- no load speed

I need help with:

- How to determine the correct DC driving voltage?
- How to compute the correct rated operating point?
- What will be the rotation speed and torque at the rated operating point?